# Compute Engine API - How to create an instance with container?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a GCE instance "with a container" (as supported by [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create-with-container)) by using `POST` [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/zones/{zone}/instances](https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/%7Bproject%7D/zones/%7Bzone%7D/instances).

How can I pass the container image url in the request payload?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the "Machine Type", then you can specify the URL following the syntax mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances).

In document:

Full or partial URL of the machine type resource to use for this instance, in the format: zones/zone/machineTypes/machine-type. This is provided by the client when the instance is created. For example, the following is a valid partial url to a predefined machine type:

zones/us-central1-f/machineTypes/n1-standard-1

To create a custom machine type, provide a URL to a machine type in the following format, where CPUS is 1 or an even number up to 32 (2, 4, 6, ... 24, etc), and MEMORY is the total memory for this instance. Memory must be a multiple of 256 MB and must be supplied in MB (e.g. 5 GB of memory is 5120 MB):

zones/zone/machineTypes/custom-CPUS-MEMORY

For example: zones/us-central1-f/machineTypes/custom-4-5120 For a full list of restrictions, read the Specifications for custom machine types.

If you instead, you want to create a container cluster, then the API method mentioned in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.clusters/create) can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...To be more precise I'm searching for the equivalent of:
`gcloud compute instances create-with-container ... --container-image=... --container-env=...` which creates an instance running "cos" and after the boot is complete it runs the declared image.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with GCP APIs, but probably using Terraform with GCP you might be able to do something like that. I recommend you to review this link [1] for further information. 

[1] https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/google_container_registry_image.html

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that there's an equivalent REST API for `gcloud compute instances create-with-container ...`, however as suggested by @user10880591's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288571/compute-engine-api-how-to-create-an-instance-with-container#comment99272768_56296703), Terraform can help. Specifically, the [container-vm module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/container-vm/google/latest) deals with the generation of metadata required for this kind of action.

Usage example can be found [here](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-container-vm/blob/7d482c08de703f858b9879f4828de9fad93adfb5/examples/instance_with_advanced_options/main.tf#L69).